# Running startup-scripts on Kubernetes Clusters

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-deployment-manager

How do I run a start script on Kubernetes cluster? I saw that there are ways to run start scripts on compute instances but couldn't find any documentation regarding the same for kubernetes clusters.

Comment: Can you check if the DeamonSet is what you are looking for? And can you describe more your use case and the need that you have to customize the VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to execute script before the actual container is started.

Init containers are specialized containers that run before app containers in a Pod . Init containers can contain utilities or setup scripts not present in an app image.

Because init containers have separate images from app containers, they have some advantages for start-up related code:

- Init containers can contain utilities or custom code for setup that
  are not present in an app image. For example, there is no need to
  make an image FROM another image just to use a tool like sed, awk,
  python, or dig during setup.
- The application image builder and deployer roles can work
  independently without the need to jointly build a single app image.
- Init containers can run with a different view of the filesystem than
  app containers in the same Pod. Consequently, they can be given
  access to Secrets that app containers cannot access.
- Because init containers run to completion before any app containers
  start, init containers offer a mechanism to block or delay app
  container startup until a set of preconditions are met. Once
  preconditions are met, all of the app containers in a Pod can start
  in parallel.
- Init containers can securely run utilities or custom code that would
  otherwise make an app container image less secure. By keeping
  unnecessary tools separate you can limit the attack surface of your
  app container image.